# Reportlab switching to landscape and then to portrait to fit table

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am trying to switch to landscape mode, in order to fit some tables and keep it somewhat readable.
I am modifying the flowable table class to set canvas to landscape

```
class CustomTable(Table):
    def __init__(self, data,  **kw):
        Table.__init__(self, data,  **kw)

    def draw(self, **kw):
        self.canv.setPageSize(landscape(letter))
        Table.draw(self, **kw)
```

The problem is, table is being rendered outside the page.
[image]